# C# class linq extension

Tags: c#, linq

I have written an extension method for two classes. Like this:

```
    public static ICollection<Class1> ExceptTestUser(this ICollection<Class1> list)
    {
        Func<Class1, bool> _func = i => !i.Name.Equals("Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        return list.Where(_func).ToList();
    }



    public static ICollection<Class2> ExceptTestUser(this ICollection<Class2> list)
    {
        Func<Class2, bool> _func = i => !i.Name.Equals("Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        return list.Where(_func).ToList();
    }
```

Both Class1 and Class2 have Name properties present.

This works fine, however, I am curious if there is any way I can create a generic method for this where I can pass the type T.

I think, this can be done by using System.Linq.Dynamic. Is there any other way to do such a thing.

Comment: Using interface is the one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface called `IHasName` and make `Class1` and `Class2` implement it:

```
interface IHasName {
    string Name { get; }
}

class Class1 : IHasName {
    ...
}

class Class2 : IHasName {
    ...
}
```

Then you can write a single method like this:

```
public static ICollection<T> ExceptTestUser<T>(this ICollection<T> list) where T : IHasName
{
    Func<T, bool> _func = i => !i.Name.Equals("Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    return list.Where(_func).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same extension method for classes without interface, you need to use reflection to get the property.

```
// Uses reflection to return value of the property or null
public static T GetPropValue<T>(this object src, string propName) where T : class
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName)?.GetValue(src, null) as T;
}

public static ICollection<T> ExceptTestUser<T>(this ICollection<T> list)
{
    // If property exists, do equality check, otherwise just accept the value
    Func<T, bool> _func = i => !i.GetPropValue<string>("Name")?.Equals("Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? true;
    return list.Where(_func).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What if the class does not have the property "Name", it would throw an exception?

Comment: It does not throw an exception, because in `GetPropValue<T>` the GetProperty method returns null and the next operator is null-coalescing `?.` in case of missing property. Also the `ExceptTestUser` has this null-coalescing operation after the `GetPropValue` and it defaults to true in case of nulls. This worked on my test cases without exceptions.